# Как считать текст между одинаковыми символами и записать его в переменную

Tags: php

По клике на кнопку в форму отправки сообщения вставляется ник пользователя которому адресовано это сообщение.
На выходе получается `@Ник получателя@, дальше возможно какой то текст`
Мне нужно получить/достать/считать Ник получателя между `@@` и записать его в переменную, чтобы потом сравнить полученный ник с ником с сессии. Если совпадают, то заменить `@@` на `span` с классом или стилем, а если не совпадают, то заменить, например, на *курсив*.
Гугл перекопал вдоль и поперек, но ничего подобного не нашел.
Ребят, помогите, пожалуйста, решит эту задачу.. Если это вообще возможно)

```js
<?php if (!in_array($autor_nick, $us_status_ban)) : ?> // проверка автора на бан

<?php if ($autor_role == 'admin') : ?> // по роли ставлю цвет ссылки и текста

<a class="link answer_link" href="profile?id=<?= $autor_id; ?>" style="color: red;"><?= $autor_nick; ?></a><br>

<p style="color: red;"><?= nl2br(showSmile($title, $pdo)); ?>// обработка текста сообщения (показ смайлов и переносы строк)

</p>
<?php elseif ($autor_role == 'moderator') : ?>
<a class="link answer_link" href="profile?id=<?= $autor_id; ?>" style="color: green;"><?= $autor_nick; ?></a><br>
<p style="color: green;"><?= nl2br(showSmile($title, $pdo)); ?></p>
<?php else : ?>
<a class="link answer_link" href="profile?id=<?= $autor_id; ?>"><?= $autor_nick; ?></a><br>
<p><?= nl2br(showSmile($title, $pdo)); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<span style="color: grey;">Автор временно не доступен - в бане <img src="/images/dirol.gif"></span>
<p><?= nl2br(showSmile($title, $pdo)); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<p>
<?= $data; ?>
</p>
<?php if ($autor_nick != $us_ses_nick) : ?>
<button id="answer_btn">Ответить</button>
<?php endif; ?>


// функция для обработки @Ник получателя@
function replace_nick ($msg, $user) {
 preg_replace_callback('/^@([^@]*?)@/u', function($m) use ($user){
  $nickname = $m[1];

  if($nickname == $user) {
   return "<span class='red'>{$nickname}</span>";
  } 
  return "<em>{$nickname}</em>";
 }, $msg);
}


// функция показа смайлов
function showSmile ($str, $pdo) {
 $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM smiles ORDER BY id DESC");
 while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
  $symbol[] = $result['title'];
  $graphics[] = '<img src="' . $result['img'] . '">';
 }

 return str_replace($symbol, $graphics, $str);
}


// в итоге если добавить функцию replace_nick до обработки 
// текста выше в коде, то получаю ошибки потому что функции
// принимают разные параметры
// если убрать функцию showSmile, а оставть replace_nick,
// то тексты всех сообщений просто исчезают
```

Comment: Ваша функция `replace_nick()` __ничего не возвращает__. Добавьте оператор _return_: [см.пример](https://ideone.com/r7QZ2Q).

Answer (score 1):

что-то вроде такого

```
 $result = preg_replace("/^@([^@]*?)@/u", "<span>$1</span>", $msg);
```

чтобы просто заменить. Или для получения значения и дальнейшей логики, примерно так:

```
 preg_replace_callback(..., function($m) use ($user){
        $nickname = $m[1];

        if($nickname == $user) {
            return "<span class='red'>{$nickname}</span>";
        } 
        return "<em>{$nickname}</em>";
   }, $msg);
```

Comment: preg_replace_callback как показалось на первый взгляд, то слишком запутанная. принимает все что угодно и в любом порядке

Comment: @ЮраБирюков в смысле все что угодно? первое там - регулярное выражение (из предыдущего примера). Второе - функция обработки. Третье - сам текст. Сама же функция для обработки на вход получает массив соответствий регулярному выражению.

Comment: ```preg_match('/\@(.+)\@/U', $str, $arr)``` тоже самое) на выходе многомерный массив. в $arr[0] лежит @ник@, а в $arr[1] лежит ник. но с заменой у меня  беда. почему то вставляется дважды span причем один span лежит в другом ```<span><span>Ник</span></span>```

Comment: @ЮраБирюков preg_match ищет соответствия, preg_replace вдобавок его заменяет.

Comment: немного подправил код. правда в обоих случаях лучше юзать спаны, только разные стили добавлять.

Comment: вообщем ничего с этого не получается. то конфликт функций, потому что принимают разные параметры в одном месте и привет ошибки, то сообщения исчезают в никуда. Благодарю за советы, подсказки и помощь.

Comment: @ЮраБирюков дак вы дополните вопрос, что и как вы делаете. без конкретики проблему за вас никто не решит.

Comment: добавил код и описание что к чему